# Prev/Next item in Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a variable with an empty array.

```
var imageData = [];
var myIndex = 0;
```

`onClick` of an element I add items to the array.

```
["item_1", "item_2", "item_3", "item_4", "item_5"]
```

This array then gets added to a div that has a background image.

```
$('.final_div').css('background-image', 'url(https://url/path/images/' + imageData[myIndex] + '.png)');
```

So i've just added a prev/next button. I added:
`myIndex = myIndex +1;` to the next button and then `myIndex = myIndex -1;` to the prev button. However, after so many iterations I get back nothing, as in myIndex is `undefined` anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

I've seen this question a few times but not sure what i've missed. Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry! Here's more full view of the code.

My array: `["item_1", "item_2", "item_3", "item_4", "item_5"]`

My next `onClick`:

```
   $('.btn-right').on('click', function(){
      myIndex = myIndex + 1;
     $('.final_div').css('background-image', 'url(https://url/path/images/' + imageData[myIndex] + '.png)');
    });
```

My prev `onClick`:

```
   $('.btn-left').on('click', function(){
      myIndex = myIndex - 1;
     $('.final_div').css('background-image', 'url(https://url/path/images/' + imageData[myIndex] + '.png)');
    });
```

Comment: give us the `onclick` code...

Comment: Sorry @shennan i've updated now :) Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using `myIndex++` and `myIndex--`?

Comment: What happens when myIndex is zero (0) and you press prev?  There is no index -1. The same for next and myIndex is the length of the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A clean solution to always keeping index inside array bounds, is to modulo the size of it. Like so:

```
myIndex = (myIndex + 1) % imageData.length;
```

This will cause `myIndex` to bounce back to 0 once it's reached the `imageData.length`.

Another approach for the same method would be:

```
myIndex++;
myIndex %= imageData.length;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're increasing `myIndex` on every click. It will soon run past the end of `imageData` (e.g. when `myIndex` is 4 in your example, incrementing to 5 will be past the end of the array).

Check that, and either go back to the beginning:

```
$('.btn-right').on('click', function(){
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex >= imageData.length)
    myIndex = 0;   

  $('.final_div').css('background-image', 'url(https://url/path/images/' + imageData[myIndex] + '.png)');
});
```

Or just stay at the end of the list:

```
$('.btn-right').on('click', function(){
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex >= imageData.length)
    myIndex = imageData.length - 1;   

  $('.final_div').css('background-image', 'url(https://url/path/images/' + imageData[myIndex] + '.png)');
});
```

The logic for "left" would be similar - either:

```
if (myIndex < 0)
  myIndex = imageData.length - 1;
```

or

```
if (myIndex < 0)
  myIndex = 0;
```